# Can a UK power cable be used with a US laptop power adapter?

Tags: power-supply

I have a US MSI GE62 Apache -002 laptop, its power adapter is rated at:

Input: 100-240V ~ 2.7A  50-60Hz

Output: 19.5V - 7.7A

Can I use it in the UK with a UK power cable?

Comment: Yes, you can. Pretty much any laptop AC adapter can handle international power these days. If it says 100-240V, you're good to go.

Comment: And most PC PSUs either auto-switch or have a switch to switch.

Comment: I guess if it says 100-240 then it's more of a universal power adaptor than a specifically US one.  US voltage only goes up to 120V but that power adaptor supports up to 240V and 240V is the UK figure. My power adaptor with my UK laptop, is 100V-240V so also, not specifically UK limited(note the power adaptor was made in china, but sold by Samsung UK for my Samsung Laptop). With those ranges it's probably not right to speak of UK and US power adaptors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can. Switch mode power supplies are magical like that. As long as you feed it *anything* within the stated voltage ranges, It'll adjust and output what its supposed to.